# QF pattern matching algorithm pseudocode to c code

Tags: c++, c, string, matching, pseudocode

the "pseudocode" described at: [here](http://www.busillis.com/o_kulekci/publications/mcs10.pdf)

BLIM is the fastest algorithm for exact string matching with long patterns.

Algorithms 3, 4, 5 are preprocessing algorithms for BLIM and Algo 6 is the actual searching code

i need help how to translate those 4 "pseudocodes" it into c code, or atleast an idea how to start.

Answer (score 1):

To understand KMP algorithm here is--[Link To understand](http://jakeboxer.com/blog/2009/12/13/the-knuth-morris-pratt-algorithm-in-my-own-words/)

```
void KMPSearch(char *pat, char *txt)
{
    int M = strlen(pat);
    int N = strlen(txt);

    // create lps[] that will hold the longest prefix suffix values for pattern
    int *lps = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*M);
    int j  = 0;  // index for pat[]

    // Preprocess the pattern (calculate lps[] array)
    computeLPSArray(pat, M, lps);

    int i = 0;  // index for txt[]
    while(i < N)
    {
      if(pat[j] == txt[i])
      {
        j++;
        i++;
      }

      if (j == M)
      {
        printf("Found pattern at index %d \n", i-j);
        j = lps[j-1];
      }

      // mismatch after j matches
      else if(pat[j] != txt[i])
      {
        // Do not match lps[0..lps[j-1]] characters,
        // they will match anyway
        if(j != 0)
         j = lps[j-1];
        else
         i = i+1;
      }
    }
    free(lps); // to avoid memory leak
}

void computeLPSArray(char *pat, int M, int *lps)
{
    int len = 0;  // lenght of the previous longest prefix suffix
    int i;

    lps[0] = 0; // lps[0] is always 0
    i = 1;

    // the loop calculates lps[i] for i = 1 to M-1
    while(i < M)
    {
       if(pat[i] == pat[len])
       {
         len++;
         lps[i] = len;
         i++;
       }
       else // (pat[i] != pat[len])
       {
         if( len != 0 )
         {

           len = lps[len-1];


         }
         else // if (len == 0)
         {
           lps[i] = 0;
           i++;
         }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome with the c code of KMPsearch i instantly understood the algorithm, i think my problem is i do not understand algorithmic notation like its the case in the paper for BLIM or QF, if someone could translate QF (algorithm 4) in this paper to c code -> https://helda.helsinki.fi/bitstream/handle/10138/18570/Long.pdf?sequence=2 i would probably understand it too but to make the leap from algo pseudo code to c myself seems impossible